# Solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g(t,z)$ be a continuous complex-valued function. Here, $t\in[-T,T]$ for some positive real  number $T$ and $z$ is complex one-dimensional. Denote $\partial / \partial t$ by $D_t$. How do we solve a differential equation of the form

$$(tD_t + \lambda)u = g$$

where $\lambda$ is a complex constant? Feel free to introduce additional assumptions if needed.

**Additional Info:** I have read that the solution is

$$u(t,z) = \int_{[0,1]} s^{\lambda - 1} g(st,z) ds. $$

Comment: Differential equations with derivatives with respect to only one independent variable are not partial, but ordinary

Comment: You can show that the solution to the homogeneous problem is $u(t)=t^{-\lambda}$ if that helps.

Comment: Look up Cauchy-Euler equations in, e.g., Wikipedia. The change of independent variable $T=\ln(t)$ will transform your ODE into a *constant coefficient*, 1st order, inhomogeneous ODE which you can solve easily by using the appropriate integrating factor. Good luck.

Comment: @automaton I have tried what you suggested and I am successful in converting the DE into a constant coefficient, 1st order, inhomogenous ODE as you said. After using an integrating factor ($e^{\lambda t}$), I get a solution but I'm not sure how to reconcile it with the one I gave above.

Comment: Tried to verify the solution you gave, but perhaps $\lambda$ has the wrong sign?

Comment: @fzlogic I'm not really sure. I don't even know how to take the derivative of the $u$ that I gave. :|

Comment: @Alex Strife - differentiating the integral is easy once you have seen it once; check the Leibniz integral rule. As for the form you give, this is in terms of the original independent variable, not the transformed one. Hence, once you have used the integrating factor ${\rm e}^{\lambda T}$ $-$ *not* ${\rm e}^{\lambda t}$, you want to be careful w/ notation on this one $-$ as we agreed, you should change the integration variable from $S$ (ranging over $[0,T]$) to $s={\rm e}^S$. That will take care of most things, except for the $g$'s first argument & range. For these, think about *rescaling* :).

Comment: @automaton3 Thanks for the hint there!

Comment: @automaton3 Doesn't Leibniz Rule require the integrand to be continuous over some rectangle? I can see how things will work if $\lambda$ is real, but will it be the same when it's complex?

Comment: You're welcome, fzlogic :). Alex, Leibniz Rule certainly requires some regularity of the integrand, which in this case is a product of a (complex) power & the inhomogeneity $g$. This brings into sight the obvious question: *what is* $s^{-\lambda-1}$ for $s\in[0,1]$? Well, if $\lambda=a+{\rm i}b$, then $s^{-\lambda-1} = s^{-(a+1)} \, s^{-{\rm i} b} = s^{-(a+1)} \, {\rm e}^{-{\rm i} b \ln(s)}$. The latter term in the RHS can now be recast using Euler's fomrula to check for regularity. Note that all of this is necessary *only to check whether what you're given is a solution*.

Comment: @automaton3 My only concern is what happens when $t=0$ (or $s=0$) - not only for checking the solution I gave. I hope you can check if what I say here is correct: In fzlogic's answer below, I can assume that $t \in (0,T]$ and everything will work (the integral can still be taken from $0$ to $t$ since the integrand is continuous on $(0,t]$). I can perform the same process for $t \in [-T,0)$. Ignoring the dependence of $s$ on $t$, the solution is consistent with the differential equation when $t=0$. Then will the solution $u(t,z)$ be continuous on all of $[-T,T]$?

Comment: @Alex - I agree that this is a valid issue (it also crops up when you work as I described above, by virtue of $\ln(s)$ appearing in the solution). It has to be expected, of course: for $t=0$, the ODE reduced to an algebraic eq. & this always means trouble :). Your sol'n will be fine, as long as the integral actually converges - whether this indeed happens, you will have to check explicitly. It is my belief that, without bounds on either of $\lambda$ and $g$, it won't. I think that this is self-evident, in fact :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Guido suggested, you can just think of this as single-variable ODE:

$$ \begin{align}
\left(t \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \lambda\right) u(t, z) &= g(t, z) \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t, z) + \frac{\lambda}{t} u(t, z) &= \frac{1}{t} g(t, z).
\end{align} $$

The standard procedure here is to evaluate the integrating factor, [*]

$$ \exp \int_1^{t} \frac{\lambda}{\tau} \operatorname{d}\! \tau = t^\lambda $$

and then proceed to solve the differential equation after multiplying by the integrating factor:

$$ \begin{align}
t^\lambda \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t, z) + \lambda t^{\lambda - 1} u(t, z) &= t^{\lambda - 1} g(t, z) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} t^\lambda u(t, z) &= t^{\lambda - 1} g(t, z) \\
u(t, z) &= \frac{1}{t^\lambda} \int_C^t \tau^{\lambda - 1} g(\tau, z) \operatorname{d}\! \tau.
\end{align} $$

Now, the solution mentioned in the question is indeed correct as well, aside from the sign error on $\lambda$ (it's easy to verify it).  Thanks to automaton3's hint, I realized that it's actually just a simple matter of rescaling the integration variable.  Let $\tau = s t$ and assume $C = 0$,

$$ \begin{align}
u(t, z) &= \frac{1}{t^\lambda} \int_0^t (s t)^{\lambda - 1} g(s t, z) \operatorname{d} (s t) \\
&= \frac{1}{t^\lambda} \int_0^t (s t)^{\lambda - 1} g(s t, z) \operatorname{d} (s t) \\
&= \frac{1}{t^\lambda} \int_{0 / t}^{t / t} t^\lambda s^{\lambda - 1} g(s t, z) \operatorname{d}\! s
\\
&= \int_0^1 s^{\lambda - 1} g(s t, z) \operatorname{d}\! s.
\end{align} $$

[*] For simplicity, the lower bound of integration were chosen arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks. I also understand now how the sign error on $\lambda$.